# Java api does not read from cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, astyanax

we are reading from cassandra ver 1 and inserting into ver 3
While reading from cassandra ver 1 I am not able to retrieve rows and in logs I see same logs in loop
For reading we are using netflix astyanax API

```
Keyspace.prepareQuery(ColumnFamily).getAllRows.execute.getResult()
```

**It works sometimes but fails majority of times**
**Do we require to configure any property in cassandra host ?**

```
DEBUG STATES: 306- [/IPaddr1:9042] Connection[/IPaddr1:9042-1, inFlight-e, closed-false] Transport initialized, connection ready
DEBUG HostConnectionPool:153 Created connection pool to host /IPaddr1:9842 (1 connections needed, 1 successfully opened)
DEBUG Session: 364 Added connection pool for /IPaddr1:9042
TRACE RequestHandler:71 [1983451872] USE <keyspace_name>
TRACE RequestHandler:272 [1983451872-1] Starting - TRACE RequestHandler: 280 [1983451872-1] Querying node nodel/IPaddr2:9042
TRACE Connection:519 Connection [node1/IPaddr2:9042-2, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 128, writing request QUERY USE <keyspace_name>([c1-LOCAL QUORUM,
positionalVals-[], namedVals-(), skip-false, psize-5000, state-null, serialCI-LOCAL SERIAL])
TRACE Connection: 567 Connection [node1/IPaddr2:9042-2, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 128, request sent successfully TRACE Connection:979 Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9042-2, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 128, received: RESULT set keyspace <keyspace_name>
TRACE RequestHandler:166 [1983451872-1] Setting Final result INFO ThriftKeyspaceImpl:640 Detected partitioner org.apache.cassandra.dht.RandomPartitioner for keyspace <keyspace_name>
TRACE RequestHandler: 71 [1955920234] com.datastax.driver.core.Statement$1@56166512 TRACE RequestHandler: 272 [1955920234-1] Starting
TRACE RequestHandler: 280 [1955920234-1] Querying node /IPaddr3:9842 = TRACE Connection:456 Connection[/IPaddr3:9842-1, inFlight-1, closed-false] Setting keyspace <keyspace_name>
TRACE Connection:519 Connection[/IPaddr3:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 128, writing request QUERY USE "<keyspace_name>"([c1-ONE, positionalVals-[],
namedVals-(), skip-false, psize--1, state-null, serialC1-SERIAL])
TRACE Connection: 567 Connection[/IPaddr3:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 128, request sent successfully TRACE Connection:979 Connection[/IPaddr3:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 128, received: RESULT set keyspace <keyspace_name>
TRACE Connection: 519 Connection[/IPaddr3:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 192, writing request PREPARE insert into table_name(...) values(...) using ttl
ttl
TRACE Connection: 567 Connection[/IPaddr3:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 192, request sent successfully
TRACE Connection:979 - Connection[/IPaddr3:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 192, received: RESULT PREPARED 8x2d705d7bcasd4e6bcf1824 [vid (int)][rdt (bigint)]
TRACE RequestHandler: 166 [1955920234-1] Setting final result
TRACE Connection:456 Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9842-2, inflight-1, closed-false] Setting keyspace <keyspace_name>
TRACE Connection:519 - Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9842-2, inflight-1, closed-false], stream 192, writing request QUERY USE namedVals-(), skip-false, psize--1, state-null, serialC1-SERIAL])
I
"<keyspace_name>" ([c1-ONE, positionalVals-[],
TRACE Connection: 567 Connection [node1/IPaddr2:9842-2, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 192, request sent successfully TRACE Connection:979 - Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9842-2, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 192, received: RESULT set keyspace <keyspace_name>
TRACE Connection:519 - Connection [node1/IPaddr2:9842-2, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 256, writing request PREPARE insert into table name (...) values (...) using ttl :ttl
TRACE Connection:567 - Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9842-2, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 256, request sent successfully TRACE Connection:456 Connection[/IPaddr1:9842-1, inFlight-1, closed-false] Setting keyspace <keyspace_name>
TRACE Connection:519 - Connection/IPaddr1:9842-1, inFlight=1, closed-false], stream 128, writing request QUERY USE "<keyspace_name>"([c1-ONE, positionalVals=[], namedVals-, skio false. osize--1. state=null, serialC1-SERIAL])
TRACE Connection:567 Connection[/IPaddr1:9042-1, inflight-1, closed-false], stream 128, request sent successfully
TRACE Connection:979 Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9042-2, inflight-1, closed-false], stream 256, received: RESULT PREPARED 0x2d785d7asdf1024 [vid (int)] [rdt (bigint)] [cts (bigint)][fd (bigint)][vd (bigint)][dv (double)][lu (bigint)][s (int)][tv (varchar)][ttl (int)] (resultMetadata=[8 columns])
TRACE Connection:979 Connection]/IPaddr1:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 128, received: RESULT set keyspace <keyspace name> TRACE Connection:519 - Connection[/IPaddr1:9842-1, inflight-1, closed-false], stream 192, writing request PREPARE insert into table_name(...) values (...) using ttl
:ttl
TRACE Connection:567- Connection[/IPaddr1:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 192, request sent successfully TRACE Connection:979 - Connection[/IPaddr1:9042-1, inFlight-1, closed-false], stream 192, received: RESULT PREPARED 0x20705d7bc168e3dea201d34e6bcf1024 [vid (int)][rdt
(bigint)][cts (bigint)][fd (bigint)][vd (bigint)][dv (double)][lu (bigint)][s (int)][tv (varchar)][ttl (int)] (resultMetadata-[9 columns])
TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 Current inFlight 1, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 Current inFlight 1, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing -
TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 Current inFlight 1, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 Current inFlight 0, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing 0 -
TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 - Current inFlight 0, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing e TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 Current inFlight 0, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing
TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 Current inflight = 0, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing
TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 Current inflight 8, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing 0.
TRACE HostConnectionPool:565 Current inFlight 0, 1 connections needed, 1 connections available, trashing DEBUG Connection:1016 Connection[nodel/IPaddr2:9042-1, inFlight-0, closed-false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
TRACE Connection:519 - Connection[nodel/IPaddr2:9842-1, inflight-0, closed-false], stream 8, writing request OPTIONS TRACE Connection:567 Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9842-1, inflight-8, closed-false], stream 0, request sent successfully
TRACE Connection:979 Connection [node1/IPaddr2:9842-1, inFlight-e, closed-false], stream 0, received: SUPPORTED (COMPRESSION-[snappy, 124], CQL_VERSION-[3.4.2]} DEBUG Connection:1886- Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9842-1, inFlight-0, closed-false] heartbeat query succeeded DEBUG Connection: 1816 Connection[nodel/IPaddr2:9842-2, inFlight-0, closed-false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
DEBUG Connection:1816- Connection[/IPaddr3:9842-1, inFlight-e, closed-false] was inactive for 30 seconds, sending heartbeat
TRACE Connection:519 Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9842-2, inFlight-0, closed-false], stream 320, writing request OPTIONS TRACE Connection:519 Connection[/IPaddr3:9842-1, inFlight-e, closed-false], stream 256, writing request OPTIONS
TRACE Connection: 567 Connection[node1/IPaddr2:9842-2, inflight-0, closed-false], stream 328, request sent successfully TRACE Connection: 567 Connection[/IPaddr3:9842-1, inFlight-0, closed-false], stream 256, request sent successfully
```

Comment: Please don't paste a large, unformatted error message and expect us to sort it out.

Comment: Which version of the Java driver are you using?

Comment: Hi Aaron, astyanax version is 1.56.x

Answer (score 0):

```
Keyspace.prepareQuery(ColumnFamily).getAllRows.execute.getResult()
```

How many rows are in this table?  Are there a lot of columns per row?  If you're seeing inconsistent results, it is probably because of this: `getAllRows`.

You might need to try using `setRowLimit` to get Astyanax to make smaller, incremental queries to Cassandra:

```
Keyspace.prepareQuery(ColumnFamily)
    .getAllRows
    .setRowLimit(10)
    .execute.getResult()
```

I'd also advise checking out Richard Low's Answer here:

[how to read all 1000 rows from cassandra CF with astyanax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17662899/how-to-read-all-1000-rows-from-cassandra-cf-with-astyanax)

It's 10 years old, and it uses the deprecated `setBlockSize` instead of `setRowLimit`.  But it might give you some ideas on how to move forward, especially if there are a lot of columns per row.

Comment: Yes we are using setRowLimit for incremental queries and column size is also 10